# Derivative of an integral of min euclidean distance

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have 2 curves: $C_1$ and $C_2$ where one is inside another, like in the picture below:

[Two curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwSuD.jpg)

Now, I am calculating the distance between them in the following way:

$E(C_1, C_2) = \int_{x_1 \in C_1} \text{min}_{x_2 \in C_2} d(x_1, x_2) dx_1$

Where $x_1$ and $x_2$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d$ is just a euclidean distance between them.

What I would like to know, is how does this distance change if I modify slightly the curve $C_2$, so I am interested in calculating:

$\frac{\partial E}{\partial C_2} = ?$

Unfortunately, my math skills are very rusty so what I am really interested in is how to do it step by step, I am not interested just in the final result.

Thanks a million for your help :)